# MySQL port forwarding

Tags: mysql, port-forwarding

I am trying to help a colleague to connect to my MySQL server. However the situation is a bit special, and here's why (let's call him person A and me, person B):

Person A has a PC, on which he has a virtual machine, which is in the same network as the actual PC he's running. However person A is also in the same network with person B (a different network).

I want the site that lives on A's VM to be able to connect to the MySQL server on B's PC. For this I've thought a port forwarding would be appropriate: from `ip-of-person-A:3306` to `ip-of-person-B:3306`. This way the site would connect to the IP of the PC it's living on (not the VM), which would forward to A's MySQL.

I've seen several examples of port forwarding, but I don't think it's what I need, from what I've seen, it's kind of the opposite. So would something like this be achievable?

Comment: Are you sure you can't just add an IP for B's network to that VM? BTW Alice and Bob are good names to use.

Comment: I'm really bad at networks & stuff, so I don't know how to add the IP for B to the VM's network, but yes, that would be even better. Alice & Bob, noted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person A can use port-forwarding with iptables on his machine, it will allow connections made to his machine 10.0.0.1 to be forwarded to PersonBs machine 172.16.0.1

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward    

personB=172.16.0.1
personA=10.0.0.1
personA_VM=10.0.0.2
personA_2=172.16.0.2
mysql=3306 # port

### Make all packets from VM to mysql go to Person B
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $mysql \ 
   -s $personA_VM/32  -d $personA  -j DNAT --to $personB:$mysql

### Make all packets local to PersonBs network.
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport $mysql \
   -s $personA_VM/32 -d $personB/32  -j MASQUERADE
```

But as I say in the comments a better solution is to add the VM to both networks

Comment: I will definitely try this. I'll also look up the suggestion from your comment. I'll get back and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: note I'm not sure how your setup looks, but this will work for some setups. It all depends where the IP packets are inserted from the VM.